# Issue with compiling gfsneohellenic with tufte-book

Tags: tufte, gfsneohellenic

I am trying to use `gfsneohellenic` with `tufte-book`. While compiling I am getting the following error.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmfdist/tex/latex/gfsneohellenic/gfsneohellenic.sty:
85: LaTeX Error: Command \textlozenge already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

MWE is appended below.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\documentclass{book} % compiles correctly with this setting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Science of why}

\end{document}
```

PS: with `\documentclass{book}` the font compiles correctly without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tufte` classes load `hyperref` prematurely, which is a cause for several kinds of problems, including yours.

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\usepackage[unicode,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfborder = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksdepth = section,
  citecolor = DarkGreen,
  linkcolor = DarkBlue,
  urlcolor = DarkGreen,
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={\plainauthor}
    pdftitle={\plaintitle},
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Science of why}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error message states, that command `\textlozenge` is defined in both packages `tufte-book` and `gfsneohellenic`. You are facing a package clash.

Since `gfsneohellenic`, as far as I understand, is about loading a font, you can bypass this definition clash by loading this font with `fontspec` and compile with `xelatex` if GFS neo hellenic is installed on your system font file, `lualatex` otherwise. Since you try to load a package, GFS neohellenic should be in your tex distribution font file and I suggest compiling with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\documentclass{book} % compiles correctly with this setting
\usepackage{fontspec}
%the fontspec way to load fonts
\setmainfont{GFS neohellenic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Science of why}

\end{document}
```

Maybe you don't know how to compile with `lualatex`: set your editor compiler to LuaLaTeX, or use latexmk `-luatex` option or type in console `lualatex document.tex` where document.tex is your file name.

[image]

PS: you can use XeLaTeX with tex font distribution either, but it needs a special declaration, check `fontspec` documentation.

PS2: your .tex file should be encoded as utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was using XeLaTeX for compilation. Will try Lua for this compilation.

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX, you don't need T1 encoding, you've got OTF fonts and utf8 out of the box. So delete the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I think reading `fontspec` doc will show you how to use also XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\textlozenge\relax
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Science of why}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem that seemed very complicated but turned out to be identical with an identical solution, my goal in this comment is to share the solution because it might help others. In my case, to solve the same problem in other circumstances, the solution was as follows

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\textlozenge\relax
```

I have not examined the problem thoroughly, but I realized that the problem was caused by the hyperref package, however I found it strange that the problem was only solved with the commands in exactly the order shown above. The fragment

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\textlozenge\relax 
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

didn't solve my problem, but I thought it should.... Well, I hope this helps someone at some point.